# How can I synchronize two scroll bars?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, scroll, richtextbox

I want to sync two scroll bars; when the user up/down scroll2 auto set scroll1 with same postion. The scroll2 is an instance of an `RichTextBox` and scroll1 is an instance of `ListView`. I have no idea how do this.

### Update

I think is closer now. Here is my current XAML code:

```
<RichTextBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="TextInput" AcceptsReturn="True" TextChanged="TextChangedEventHandler" Margin="0,23,0,9" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="OnScrollChangedHandler" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="432.493">
            <RichTextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </RichTextBox.Resources>
        </RichTextBox>

    <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollRow" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="OnRowsScrollChangedHandler" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,23,0,7.02" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="40">
                    <StackPanel Name="pScrollRow">
                      <ListView Margin="0,23,0,9" Name="Rows">
                        1.
                      </ListView>
          </StackPanel>
           </ScrollViewer>
```

C# code:

```
// ... 

 private void OnScrollChangedHandler(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((IScrollInfo)pScrollRow).SetHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an event handler for ScrollBar.ValueChanged for both boxes, and have them change each other's ScrollBar.Value to the corresponding value. I haven't tested this, but seems reasonable! Good luck!

Comment: Was first thing that I thought, but the problem is how to get/set scroll positions. I don't know how do I to get them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to add Element binding to sync the values, so you do not need to any code.
Here's the details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) about the element binding.

Comment: well.. I tried it,but it returns the following error: `A 'Binding' can not be used in a collection 'ItemCollection'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.` can you post an example code?