# how to find .Handle of RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

in winForms, I have [.Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx) property, how do I get the equivalent to in WPF?

I tried using [WindowInteropHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx) but it does not suporte `RichTextBox`,only `Window` types.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even in Winforms, this property is giving you the Window handle --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx  ("Gets the window handle that the control is bound to.")

Comment: This is pretty core in WPF, controls are not windows.  Just paint, made to *look* like a window.  And a boatload of code to make them behave like a window.  Thus no Handle property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controls in WPF do not have associated WinAPI handle, like WinForms control do. WPF uses only one WinAPI window to process window messages from OS and encapsulates it in Window class instance. The best you can do is to navigate through parents of your control until you find a Window and get the handle. As far as I understand this will likely be the same handle as one returned by WindowInteropHeler.

**UPD.**
To make this answer more useful and out-of-box'y here is some code (not tested though):

```
IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(Window.GetWindow(userControlRefernce)).Handle;
```

Comment: I can't believe! but if I need call a function from `Win32API`... can't I? currently, I'm tried do this in WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332788/maintain-scroll-position-of-treeview but in my case, I want to sync:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028524/how-can-i-synchronize-two-scroll-bars

Answer (score 2):

`RichTextBox` does not have `HWND` handle in WPF. You can still use a `RichTextBox` from WinForms library using `WindowsFormsIntegration` assembly, if you really need this handle.

Remember that you can always check what elements have or do not have handles using `Spy++` utility.

Comment: oh,no.. I can't to use RichTextBox of winForms, the main reason to use WPF in this project, was the resources of RichTextBox in WPF that RichTextBox of winForms have no. (I'm writing a simply text editor with highlight). Thanks for your tip about spy++ use. next time, I'II do use it.